# How to remove double quotes from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, read.csv

I'm still quite new to python and I have been trying to figure out a way to remove the double quotes and split the fields within the quotes from a csv file.

for example:
the imported data from the csv file consists of a row with the following:

```
data: 1 ; "2;3" ; "4;5" ; 6
```

the desired output I would be going for would be:

```
output: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6
```

I have tried using the following code to achieve this although it doesn't recognize the semicolon within the quotes as a delimiter:

```
with open('file.csv','r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='"' )
next(csv_reader)
output = ""
for line in csv_reader:
        output +=  line[0] + ',' + line[1]+ ',' + line[2] + ',' + line[3] + ',' + line[4] + ',' + line[5]
print(output)
```

Comment: If its only removing the quotes and flattening the string, you dont need csv libs, a simple list comprehension will do.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you applied. You can [edit] your question to fix that. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour], in case you haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, skipinitialspace=True)
    output = ""
    # iterate over every line of the csv
    for line in csv_reader:
        # iterate over each element of the line
        for i in range(len(line)):
            line[i] = line[i].strip(" ").strip("\"")
        output += ", ".join(line) + "\n"  # remove the "\n" if you want no return character
    print(output)
```

Comment: @marshmallow Great! If you wouldn't mind since it works marking my answer as correct, I would appreciate it. If you have any other bumps you encounter along the way let me know and I'll see if I can help out! :)